# Buscador Flask MySQL en un modelo MVC no funciona

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Estoy intentando crear un **BUSCADOR** con Flask que encuentre resultados en una base de datos MySQL tengo problemas en traer datos al buscar datos que no estén escritos exactamente como están guardados en mi BD. Dejaré comentado lo que me están devolviendo los prints
FUNCIÓN DE MI MODELO

```
    @classmethod
    def search(cls, data):
        tipo = type(data)
        print("DATA TYPE", tipo ) #DATA TYPE <class 'str'>
        instance_results = []
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE %s ORDER BY id DESC"
        results = connectToMySQL('lab_bd').query_db(query, (data + '%',))
        print("RESULTADOS de mi query", results)#RESULTADOS de mi query False
        for result in results:
            instancia = cls(result)
            instance_results.append(instancia)
        return instance_results
```

FUNCIÓN DE MI CONTROLADOR

```
@app.route('/show/patients', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_patients():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'txtname' in request.form:
        name = request.form["txtname"]
        users = User.search(name)
    else:
        users = User.get_all()
    return render_template("searcher.html", users=users)
```

**Antes hice esto pero solo funciona como dije en la descripcion**
mi data en mi ruta era `data = {"first_name": name}`
y mi consulta`query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE %(first_name)s ORDER BY id DESC"`

Y esta es la conexion a mi base de datos, no sé si este es el problema porque aqui adentro me imprime unos errores. Lo hago de esta forma para poder prevenir inyeccion sql. Dejaré comentado lo que me están devolviendo los prints

```
import pymysql.cursors

class MySQLConnection:
    def __init__(self, db):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                                    user = 'root',
                                    password = '', 
                                    db = db,
                                    charset = 'utf8mb4',
                                    cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                                    autocommit = True)
        self.connection = connection
    def query_db(self, query, data=None):
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                query = cursor.mogrify(query, data)
                print("Running Query:", query)#Running Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE 'lui%' ORDER BY id DESC
     
                executable = cursor.execute(query, data)
                if query.lower().find("insert") >= 0:
                    self.connection.commit()
                    return cursor.lastrowid
                elif query.lower().find("select") >= 0:
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    return result
                else:
                    self.connection.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Something went wrong", e)#Something went wrong unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 47
                return False
            finally:
                self.connection.close() 
def connectToMySQL(db):
    return MySQLConnection(db)
```